# Creating fixture with block format instead of inline format in django

Tags: django, fixtures, pyyaml

I am using `pyyaml`.
I'm using following command to create fixtures in django project:

```
python manage.py dumpdata app.ModelName --format=yaml  > fixtures/dev/fixture_name.yaml
```

What I get as output is:

```
- fields: {active: true, created_at: !!timestamp '2016-11-14 10:43:40.221602', age: 54,
    updated_at: !!timestamp '2016-11-14 10:43:40.221603', user_type: 1}
  model: app.ModelName
  pk: 1
```

What I want is:

```
- fields:
    created_at: 2016-11-14 10:43:40.220895
    age: 54
    user_type: 1
    updated_at: 2016-11-14 10:43:40.220900
  model: app.ModelName
  pk: 1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where is the source for `manage.py`?

Answer (score 0):

In `manage.py`, you are calling `dump()` (or `safe_dump()` incorrectly. You should call it with arguments

```
 dump(your_data, default_flow_style=False)
```

you also have to provide a representer for `timestamp` as that is not a type that PyYAML knows about. Or use (a subclass of) `datetime.datetime` for which PyYAML knows how to represent it.